# Tag Cloud library in Java

Tags: java, open-source, tag-cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I generate a tag cloud in Java, with OpenCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481482/how-can-i-generate-a-tag-cloud-in-java-with-opencloud)

I would like to know if there's an open source library (JAR) available to generate a tag-cloud in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output you need should be in HTML you can use OpenCloud: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencloud/

Comment: Jack, Thanks for the answer ! However, wouldn't it require a web server to display the tag cloud? Isn't an offline option available?

Comment: It can also be used into a website but basically you populate the tagcloud and then you can get the tags list with the size of every single tag and do whatever you want, you should check documentation inside the zip of the library..

Comment: Jack, Thanks. I was able to resolve the issue

Comment: This library uses a lot of scriplets which have negative influence in jsp page ...