# How can I generate a tag cloud in Java, with OpenCloud?

Tags: java, swing, api, tags, word-cloud

I was looking for a library to create tag clouds in a Java application, and I found [OpenCloud](http://opencloud.mcavallo.org/).

I don't want to have to use a web server, which OpenCloud will require to get the output in, won't it?  Is there a way to get OpenCloud to work in a Java/Swing panel? I want something for a stand alone application. If this isn't possible, where else can I look for such an API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually OpenCloud does not require a Web server. Simply use Swing rendering instead of HTML/JSP. Here is a small snippet illustrating a very basic Swing tag cloud using OpenCloud library. It can be improved, but it gives you the gist:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.mcavallo.opencloud.Cloud;
import org.mcavallo.opencloud.Tag;

public class TestOpenCloud {

    private static final String[] WORDS = { "art", "australia", "baby", "beach", "birthday", "blue", "bw", "california", "canada", "canon",
            "cat", "chicago", "china", "christmas", "city", "dog", "england", "europe", "family", "festival", "flower", "flowers", "food",
            "france", "friends", "fun", "germany", "holiday", "india", "italy", "japan", "london", "me", "mexico", "music", "nature",
            "new", "newyork", "night", "nikon", "nyc", "paris", "park", "party", "people", "portrait", "sanfrancisco", "sky", "snow",
            "spain", "summer", "sunset", "taiwan", "tokyo", "travel", "trip", "uk", "usa", "vacation", "water", "wedding" };

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestOpenCloud.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Cloud cloud = new Cloud();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (String s : WORDS) {
            for (int i = random.nextInt(50); i > 0; i--) {
                cloud.addTag(s);
            }
        }
        for (Tag tag : cloud.tags()) {
            final JLabel label = new JLabel(tag.getName());
            label.setOpaque(false);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont((float) tag.getWeight() * 10));
            panel.add(label);
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestOpenCloud().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This code is based on the Example 1 of the [OpenCloud library](http://opencloud.mcavallo.org/)

Here is an output of what I got:

[image: Swing tag cloud demo image]

Comment: Can this Api support hover function and linking?

Comment: @user1525144 Sure, all you need is to add a MouseListener on each JLabel upon mouse clicked events, you can use `Desktop.getDesktop().browse()`, upon mouseEntered/mouseExited you can act for the hovering. You can also set the cursor to `Cursor.getPredefinedCursor()` on each JLabel.

Comment: Thank you so much.Is opencloud the best api available for java tag cloud creation?

Comment: @user1525144 No idea. It's the first time I used it. There are maybe other API available but it's the only open source I found.

Answer (score 15):

I created the word cloud library, Kumo (Cloud in Japanese), in Java. Oddly, I've always liked word clouds. :)

Kumo can generate BufferedImages, image files (PNG,BMP,etc), and also has examples showing usage in JPanels. The project is mavenized and in Maven Central to make integration easier. Below are a few example word clouds and there are more examples on Kumo's GitHub page: https://github.com/kennycason/kumo

There is also a JPanel example [here](https://github.com/kennycason/kumo/blob/master/kumo-core/src/test/java/com/kennycason/kumo/examples/JPanelDemo.java) and a screenshot [here](https://github.com/kennycason/kumo/blob/master/kumo-core/output/jpanel_example.png).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just wanted to chime in here and say that after evaluating opencloud and kumo as my options, Kumo was the clear winner here. I am not even sure if OpenCloud is actively maintained any more. The old SourceForge page for OC spammed my browser. :/

Answer (score 1):

I've used openCloud to create simple java word clouds using word frequency and or log likelihood values to adjust the words weight (font size). The clouds use random colours and provide a simple random rotation.

Github repository [here](https://github.com/drelhaj/Java_WordCloud_LogLikelihood)

[English sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lmvP.png)

[Arabic sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuRli.png)